# Import error for rospy in Python3.6 script

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried import rospy into a python script that requires python3.6, but it gives me the error:
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospy'**

I'm able to successfully import the rospy into a python3.5 script.

So how can I install rospy package for python3.6 ??
When running in python 3.6 I first remove the path to the python2.7 link.

This works:

```
 dev@dev:~/tool_system$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rospy
>>>
```

This does not work:

```
 dev@dev:~/tool_system$ python3.6
  Python 3.6.10 (default, Dec 19 2019, 23:04:32) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.remove('/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
>>> import rospy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospy'
>>>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347402/import-error-for-rospy-in-python3.6-script/) by [mysqo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44877/mysqo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-pkg-modules
sudo apt-get install python3-rospkg-modules
```

Refer: Gustavo's answer - https://answers.ros.org/question/245967/importerror-no-module-named-rospkg-python3-solved/?answer=298221#post-id-298221

---

Originally posted by [nkhedekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/34897/nkhedekar/) with karma: 138 on 2020-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-03-25**:
Please note: this will only work for whatever the system default provided version of Python 3 is for the version of Debian/Ubuntu on which you run that `apt` command.

For Ubuntu Bionic, that would be `3.6.x` I believe. Seeing as the OP shows two versions of Python which are different from that series, I assume he's installed those manually. The packages you mention will most likely not be available for those versions.